# In which cases should I use caching?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis

I am building a website based on a MySQL database. The website will get a lot of tables, a lot of rows, and a lot of views. I know that because I am building a new system to an existing website.

The current website is using MySQL only, without caching, and it causes a lot of problems like bad performance and database crashes.

On the new system I'd like to avoid that by using a caching engine like *Redis*, but the real problem is that I don't quite understand what data should be cached, or in what cases.

Should I cache:

- Everything?
- Large/small tables?
- All data / only part of it?

How should I use caching?

- Store all data in MySQL, and cache only some of records? (example: recent articles)
- Store some data on Redis only? (example: article views/IP address table)

I don't exactly want you to answer directly to my question, I just need a guidance for using caching.

Answer (score 0):

I use `apache-ignite` as a cache, where I store only the most accessed data, like reporting entities, in your case might be the recently added articles (you need to decide upon that).

Depending on your hardware, because ignite or any cache, store data on RAM so you should think of this aspect when you decide what to cache.

You said the you want to store articles, only the most recent ones, well you can choose to replicate only the articles which have the creationDate earlier then two weeks ago.

[Ignite also provides an ORM](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.0/docs/persistent-store) tool which is used to couple ignite to the database and this can be configured in two way, to immediately update the database if the cache is changed or when it decides to do that.